# Close to a proof that every such equicontinuous sequence of functions converges uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a compact metric space; let $Y$ be a normed space; let $\{ f_{n} \} \subset \mathscr{C}(X, Y)$ be equicontinuous; and let $f_{n} \to g$ pointwisely for some $g: X \to Y$. **Claim:** We have $f_{n} \to g$ uniformly.

I think I am close to a proof of the claim. 
Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\{f_{n}\}$ is equicontinuous by assumption, for every $x \in X$, by definition there is some $X$-open $U \ni x$ such that 
$|f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(y)| < \varepsilon$ for all $y \in U$ and all $n \geq 1$.
Since $X$ is compact by assumption, so by definition there are some $X$-open $U_{1}, \dots, U_{k}$ covering $X$; let $x_{i} \in U_{i}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$.
Since $f_{n} \to g$ pointwisely by assumption, by definition there is some $N \geq 1$ such that
$|g(x_{i}) - f_{n}(x_{i})| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ and all $1 \leq i \leq k$.

I made use of all the assumptions, but, what is a thing I overlooked so that I cannot continue the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing with what you did, let $y \in X$ be arbitrary. Then $y \in
U_i$ for some $i$. Hence,

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&|f_n (y) -f_m (y)| \\&\leq &|f_n (y)-f_n (x_i)|+|f_n
(x_i)-g(x_i)|+|g(x_i)-f_m(x_i)|+|f_m (x_i)-f_m(y)| \\ &<&4\epsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
for sufficiently large $n,m$ (where "sufficiently large" does **not**
depend on $y\in X$.

We have thus shown that the sequence $(f_n)_n$ is uniformly Cauchy. By
classical results, it thus has a (uniform) limit $h$ in
$C(X,\overline{Y})$, where $\overline{Y}$ is the completion of $Y$.

Since you know that the pointwise limit is given by $g$, we get $g=h$
and thus the desired uniform convergence.

I am sure that one can eliminate the whole "completion of $Y$
argument", but if you are satisfied with the argument as it is, I will
not do so :)

Comment: Thank you! The last thing I am not quite sure: How are the two differences involving $x_{i}$ and $y$ made $< \varepsilon$? From equicontinuity or something else?

Comment: @GudsonChou: This comes essentially from your proof attempt. We get for each $x \in X$ some open set $U_x$ with $|f_n (x) - f_n (y)| < \varepsilon$ for all $n$ and $y \in U_x$ (that should be your definition of equicontinuity?). Now, by compactness, there are $x_1, \dots, x_k \in X$ with $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^k U_{x_i}$. Now, by pointwise convergence at the (finitely many!) points $x_i$, there is $N$ with $|f_n (x_i) - g(x_i)| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Since (in my proof above) we have $y \in U_i$, we then have $|f_n(y) - f_n (x_i)| < \varepsilon$ for all $n$ and we are done (as above).

Comment: Thanks! Now I can clearly locate the point of unsureness: How does $y \in U_{i}$ imply $|f_{n}(y) - f_{n}(x_{i})| < \varepsilon$ for all $n$? This is probably a cause that I could not complete a proof...

Comment: @GudsonChou: This holds by choice of $U_i = U_{x_i}$. You write yourself that "for every $x \in X$, by definition there is some $X$-open $U$ [which I call $U_x$ for concreteness] such that $|f_n (x) - f_n (y)| < \epsilon$ for all $y \in U$ and all $n \geq 1$". Now apply this with $y \in U = U_{x_i} = U_i$.

Comment: But, as I see it, $U_{x_{i}}$ is a choice by compactness and need not be a choice by equicontinuity?

Comment: @GudsonChou: You first choose (given $\epsilon$) the family of sets $U_x$ for **all** $x \in X$. These form an open cover of $X$. Using compactness, we then select certain $x_1, \dots, x_k$ (which certainly depend on $\epsilon$, since the $U_x$ do) with $X = \bigcup_{j=1}^k U_{x_j}$. Now each of the $U_{x_j}$ is a special $U_x$ (namely for $x = x_j$), which implies  validity of the property that I am using.

Comment: Ah ha, thanks a lot! that is what I confused myself... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not generally true as written. Look at the statement of Ascoli-Arzela. You need uniform boundedness, and then you still only get convergence of a subsequence.

Comment: Thank you. Since the statement is close to Dini's theorem, but a little bit trade off  in conditions (from $Y = \mathbb{R}$ to $Y$ normed space and from $(f_{n})$ a sequence of continuous functions to $(f_{n})$ an equicontinuous sequence), it looks to me likely to be true.

Comment: @GudsonChou: It is true indeed, as my answer shows.